# PHP Mysql order by time

Tags: php, mysql

categories and scheduler

categories

```
id  name    start_date               end_date
 1   cat1    2014-04-02 00:00:00      2014-04-12 10:00:00
 2   cat2    2014-04-12 12:00:00      2014-04-12 13:00:00
 3   cat3    2014-04-01 00:00:00      2014-04-12 11:00:00
```

and scheduler table is

```
id name  firetime     runonce
1   1    1397651700    1
2   1    1397652200    2 
3   2    1397654100    2
```

like this. In scheduler table, name is categories table's id and firetime is strtotime of start_date and end_date. runonce called start_date and end_date reference.

If the firetime less than now date, it automatically deleted, but not categories. Here I want to sort by firetime which is ready for next fire. And fired categories should show below.

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY sale_start_date, sale_end_date
```

Here, how to match with scheduler table and sort by upcoming fire date.

Comment: firetime is a TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: Why do you store time in 2 formats: DATETIME and INT ? Can you show your expected result? Even better, can you create a SQLFiddle?

Comment: @Prakash, your query is working or not... tell me quickly//

Comment: Its sort by start date and end date. But I want sort by which is ready for firing and fired should be last record

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM scheduler ORDER BY firetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Your database has a very bad structure.  Columns representing the same thing (date/time values) have different formats.  Foreign key references have no name similarity (`id`, `name`).

I think you want a `join` and aggregation.  Based on the information in your question, it is something like this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM categories c join
     scheduler s
     on s.firetime between strtotime(sale_start_date) and strtotime(sale_end_date) and
        s.name = c.id
ORDER BY sale_start_date, sale_end_date;
```